# NewProxyPreparedStatement implements PreparedStatement, but does not fulfil the contract?

Tags: java, c3p0

I have a c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource, managed by Spring, managing my database connections. When I [grab a PreparedStatement instance from a connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29), I find that C3P0 is actually returning me an instance of the NewProxyPreparedStatement class which implements the PreparedStatement Interface. Fine.

However, when I call some of the methods defined as part of this contract I get the following RuntimeException *java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.isClosed()Z*

[Looking at the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.mchange/c3p0/0.9.2-pre4/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/NewProxyPreparedStatement.java?av=h), I can see that this class does not provide a number of methods which are outlined as part of the Statement and PreparedStatement contract. This code shouldn't compile. I feel like I am missing something important, but quite advanced here. How is it possible that this is shipped as part of a library?

I was hoping to use the PreparedStatement.isClosed method, is the actual underlying problem that I should just be leaving the management of these Objects to Spring?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest pre-release of c3p0-0.9.5, which supports all JDBC4 api. The version you are using supports only JDBC3. If you like managed dependencies, use groupId: com.mchange, artifactId: c3p0, version: 0.9.5-pre5. Otherwise [binary distributions are on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/files/c3p0-bin/).